# How can I create h264 video from series of images on Android

Tags: android, h.264

I am using jcodec to create video from series of images on android. Then I have to add audio to that video. I have tested mp4parser library and it works probably. The problem is that Jcodec in Android( NOT JAVA) is only produce MP4 but cannot generate h264 and mp4parser needs h264 as an input. Anyone knows how can I create Raw h264 video from series of images in Android?

Thanks a lot

Comment: hi, i have the same issue. have u solve the problem?  
i've got
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use an MP4 clip as input for the muxing process:

```
    Movie m = MovieCreator.build("Path/to/your/video-mp4");
    AACTrackImpl audio = new AACTrackImpl(new FileDataSourceImpl("Path/to/your/aac"));
    m.addTrack(audio);

    Container c = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(m);
    c.writeContainer(new FileOutputStream("/path/to/your/destination.mp4").getChannel());
```

I hope that helps

Comment: I could compile Maven and use your library but still I get same error :  `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4` , My MP4 can be palyed with player but I think its not h264, and that is why MP4Parser cannot paly it, am I right?

Comment: I have created my movie from images using Jcodec, I am stuck to add audio but I dont want to use ffmpeg. Can I still use MP4Parser? I get error from here Container c = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(m);

Comment: Hi,
could you send me the complete stacktrace? This error message doesn't help as it is totally generic and could occur anywhere.

Comment: `FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4 at com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.builder.DefaultMp4Builder.createStco(DefaultMp4Builder.java:413)
 at com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.builder.DefaultMp4Builder.createStbl(DefaultMp4Builder.java:313)
 at com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.builder.DefaultMp4Builder.createTrackBox(DefaultMp4Builder.java:274)
 at com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.builder.DefaultMp4Builder.createMovieBox(DefaultMp4Builder.java:186)

Comment: `com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.builder.DefaultMp4Builder.build(DefaultMp4Builder.java:88) at com.csw.zwitsal.VideoCreateation$MovieCreator$1.onClick(VideoCreateation.java:924) at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
`

Comment: `com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Had to divide it to different comments due to limitation of characters

Comment: Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: which version are you using? Do you use a release? Or do you compile on your own (don't do that, plz!)

Comment: oh, I have compiled by my own, would you give me the link to download the release version? from https://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/ I have gotten and compiled. Can you give me the last released version? Thanks a lot

Comment: please go to https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser
googlecode is obsolete as stated on the landing page

Comment: @SebastianAnnies hi, i've got the same issue. 
I've create a mp4 from a image using ffmepg. Then i tried to add a sound track, The video's sample size is 74, the audio's ample size is 8889.  and the Exception is : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=73; index=73

I'm sure i've install the mp4parser right, because i can merge two video successfully.